# Javascript calls C# code and parser error

Tags: 2013, development, ajax, json

I am trying to get my javascript to call some C# code that I have added to my Sharepoint site. Unfortunately every time it runs, I'm not getting the **"Success"** i had programmed in. Instead I get this:

[image: image 1]

My Javascript code:

```
function test() {     
             $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'NewForm.aspx/doThis',
             data: "",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success");
             },
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
             }
         });
     };
```

And My C# code:

```
    [WebMethod]                                
 public static void doThis()
{
  //Code
}
```

The code is not supposed to do anything yet, but print out success if it was able to get to the method.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? Did you try using some other browser , did it give the same error ?

Comment: Firefox I get the same Request and status but the Error is: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Chrome I get: Unexpected Token  <

Comment: are you using SP 2013 or SP2010 and using spservices(https://spservices.codeplex.com/) or plain javascript

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Sharepoint Online 2013 and using SPservices version 2014.02